# XQuery and html conditional comments

Tags: xquery, conditional-comments, marklogic

After reading some of the other questions on here and trying their solutions, I still have this issue with XQuery.

We are using a conditional comment to see if IE is being used. We are dynamically building paths to our javascript files like so.

```
<!--[if lte IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$layout:cdnPath}/scripts/browser-detect-admin.js">&nbsp;</script>
<![endif]-->
```

But it seems that the script element is being evaluated as text and not building the correct path to our javascript. It is thinking that {$layout:cdnPath}/scripts/browser-detect-admin.js is the path to the file. I can't figure out why.

I tested this in IE 7,8 and also in IE 9 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. Such expression templates are not evaluated within literal comment. Use a comment constructor instead:

```
comment {concat('[if lte IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="', $layour:cdnPath, '/scripts/browser-detect-admin.js">&nbsp;</script>
<![endif]')}
```

HTH

Comment: It works! The weird thing is it used to work the way we had it then stopped. So who knows.

Comment: That could have been a bug fix, although I am not aware of one. Reading http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-DirCommentConstructor it seems fairly clear to me. Comments are `"<!--" DirCommentContents "-->"` and `DirCommentContents := ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))*`. You expected the `EnclosedExpr` behavior, which is not available in directly constructed comments.